# How can I fix java.sql.BatchUpdateException?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, batch-updates

I write a java program that connect to mysql db with jdbc.It inserts records to mysql.
The sql is this:

```
 INSERT   INTO my_schema.my_table VALUES ('AMERICAN', '97', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', 'United States Dollar', 'USD', '$', '2', 'Y', 'Y', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '_6064530F8DBAB938E040007F010015E3' );
```

But it gives this error:

```
e = (java.sql.BatchUpdateException) java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('AMERICAN', '40', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', 'Ja' at line 1
```

But the weird thing is : I insert it manually without error.

thanks in advance,

Comment: do you have a auto incremented primary key in the table ?

Comment: no I do not have primary key

Comment: hmm the error looks like due to having some quote in the string somewhere.

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar: Can you post java code that creates batch statements and how values are set in the sql statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is weird but it works:

I just remove the last character  **semicolon** , and it works:

I mean I change this:

```
INSERT   INTO my_schema.my_table VALUES ('AMERICAN', '97', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', 'United States Dollar', 'USD', '$', '2', 'Y', 'Y', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '_6064530F8DBAB938E040007F010015E3' );
```

to this:

```
INSERT   INTO my_schema.my_table VALUES ('AMERICAN', '97', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '10', 'United States Dollar', 'USD', '$', '2', 'Y', 'Y', '1995-08-28 00:00:00', '_6064530F8DBAB938E040007F010015E3' )
```